# Need to use text to columns function (Delimited) on Different WorkBook

Tags: excel, vba

The code provided works on its own workbook but i need it to work on a different workbook

```
Dim objRange1 As Range 'text to columns parse

'Set up the ranges
Set objRange1 = Range("B1:B300")

'Do the first parse
objRange1.TextToColumns _
  Destination:=Range("B1"), _
  DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  Tab:=False, _
  Semicolon:=False, _
  Comma:=False, _
  Space:=False, _
  Other:=True, _
  OtherChar:=":"
```

Comment: You need to add a reference to the workbook object you want to use. If this code you have here is in the workbook or worksheet object module you need to move it to  a regular module. If the workbook you want the code to run on is closed you will need to open it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook

Comment: So i added it and it still dd nothing. Heres what i did:

Comment: Sub Testt()
Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production").Activate

    Dim objRange1 As Range 'text to columns parse

    'Set up the ranges
    Set objRange1 = Range("B1:B300")

    'Do the first parse
    objRange1.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production").Range("B1"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, _
      OtherChar:=":"


End Sub

Comment: Sorry idk how to format it

Comment: @matt.auerbach you might want to edit the question and put the code of what you tried in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim objRange1 as range
with workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Production")
    set objrange1 = .range("B1:B300")
    objrange1.texttocolumns _
    Destination:=.Range("B1"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, _
    Space:=False, _
    Other:=True, _
    OtherChar:=":"
end with
```

Comment: On which line do you get that?

Comment: Not sure how to check. is there a way to check inside of excel?

Comment: Yes open up the developer window and press f8 until you get the error

Comment: All that is doing is putting "Extend Selection" in the bottom left corner

Comment: hold alt then press f11, That will open a new window. Navigate to where your code is stored in that new window. Click within the subroutine then press f8.

Comment: I think it is on the "End With" Line

Comment: It isn't on that line, there is no object. The only error that I've seen occurring on ```end with``` is a compile error for not having an opening ```with```

Comment: Because when i do the F8 thing it highlights everything in yellow and right before the "End with" it gives the error pop up